# Two or more yes/no questions in a script?

Tags: bash, debian, bash-script

I'm writing a bash script which has a "yes/no" question in it, but now I want to have another yes/no question in it. The script can only cope with one yes/no, so how can I have two, or more, yes/no questions in?

The yes/no script is:

```
read -p "Do you want to install this programme? " yn 
case $yn in 
[Yy]* ) sudo apt-get install "$programme";; 
[Nn]* ) exit;; 
* ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";; 
esac 
exit
```

Comment: This question is unclear. There is no indication of _why_ the script can only cope with only one yes/no question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you may be running into here is one of scope. In other words, a variable's value is set at a certain point in your script, and that variables value is retained throughout. Later, you run into the issue that since the variable is defined (i.e., has a value), your conditional does evaluate as expected.

Here's a code sample to give you an example

```
foo ()
{
    local yn
    read -p "Do you want to install this programme? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo $yn;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";;
    esac
}
foo
echo $yn
```

Now, notice when you run that code sample that when $yn is echo'd withing the scope of foo() that it comes back with what you've entered, yet outside that scope it is empty. When I declare the variable local to the foo function (e.g., {}), it is undefined outside of that. If you want to reuse variable names without having them conflict with one another, this is how it is done.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, its working except its blowing an error saying that 'local: can only be used in a function', but it still works. how then can we either hide the error message, or clear it please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the question, but I presume I do.

Just use different variable name with each question, if you want to retain those choices for later perusal in your script.

Ie. just copy-and-paste what you have there, but change `yn` to `yn_2` for example, then use that variable in your case statement as well.